# How to Read Key pressed in python

Tags: python, keypress

How do you move a circle up, down and side to side, without downloading other things (`pygame`)?  I tried using `getch` but it would not work.  Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
import msvcrt

key = msvcrt.getch()
while True:
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you should use

```
if msvcrt.kbhit():
    c = msvcrt.getch()
```

inside a polling loop.

Comment: and then to see see the key press 'print c'

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything other than installing a module. I would strongly recommend you use [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). Its easy to use and unlike other modules, it'll work.

Here is an example code which will detect `c`:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("c"):  #It will not include capital C
        print("C pressed!")
        break
```

It will receive keys from the whole Windows